# Where are tokens stored after authentication with ADB2C?

Tags: azure, authentication, token, azure-ad-b2c

I am a beginner when it comes to authentication.
I recently created a login screen using ADB2C's custom policies.
I believe a token is issued at that time, where is it stored?
cookie?localStrage?
I'm sorry for my ignorance, but please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the application type - did you develop a single page app[SPA], asp.net app, or windows WPF? Based on the client side library it will be stored - in case of browser based app, it will be in cookies or `localStorage`. For instance, if you used `MSAL` angular module in angular app, then the value of `cacheLocation` when you called `PublicClientApplication` method determines it.

Comment: I am using React to create SPA.
So, The screen transition flow is Login Form → MFA → SPA.
Where would this be stored in this case?

Comment: So, in your React app, which library are you using? If msal.js, then my answer already covers it.

Comment: Is MSAL the default library for ADB2C?
There are many things I don't understand and have not consciously used until now.

Comment: If you follow this tutorial, you will understand better. See [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react#create-your-project)

Comment: Thank you, your advice.
After looking at the tutorial, I figured I would use MSAL-React.
My login screen consists of ADB2C custom policies, while the main screen SPA is in React.
Since it is the SPA that holds the token after login, I have decided to use MSAL-React.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. You can mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice despite my bad English.